# authentication with an openid auth 2.0 provider in asp core web app

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, openid, identity

I'm trying to create an web relyng party in asp core 2  with and external login scheme for and openid identity server ([rediris](http://www.rediris.es/sir/howto-openid.html)).

The problem is that the external identity server uses its own framework ([papi](http://papi.rediris.es/)) with the following characteristics:

1. specs [open id authentication 2.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html) and [simple registration extension](https://openid.net/specs/openid-simple-registration-extension-1_0.html)
2. Discovery of type html-discovery (only obtain the provider and ns)
3. don´t have a userinfo endpoint

Problem and solutions:

1. Get the identity provider with html-discovery -> solved
2. with smart mode, make an association and obtain "assoc_handle", "mac_key" and "expires_in" -> solved.
3. get the OP Identifier  -> solved.
4. i need create a challenge to make and authentication request and after login in the external server, obtain the response with the temporal keys and the user supplied identifier (select by the user in the login redirection in openid provider)

I have tried several ways but none of them allows me to return to my return_url

Setup of Authentication / OpenidConnect (don´t work):

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
{
    o.ClientId = "ClientId";
    o.ClientSecret = "ClientSecret";
    o.ResponseType = "code"; 
    o.Authority = "https://yo.rediris.es/papoid-server.php";
    //o.ProtocolValidator.RequireNonce = true;
    o.SaveTokens = true;
    o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false;
    o.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.FormPost;
    //test with claims   
    o.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("sub", "sub");
    o.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("name", "name");
    o.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("profile", "profile");
    o.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("email", "email");
    o.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("fullname", "fullname");
    o.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email"); 
    o.Scope.Add("openid");
   //o.Scope.Add("phone");
    o.Scope.Add("email");
    o.Scope.Add("address");
}
```

Necessary Request to create:

```
POST https://yo.rediris.es/papoid-server.php HTTP/1.1

openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
&openid.ns.sreg=http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1
&openid.sreg.required=nickname,email
&openid.sreg.optional=fullname
&openid.realm=http://localhost:5002/
&openid.mode=checkid_setup 
&openid.return_to=http://localhost:5002/login?nonce=whatevercode
&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
&openid.claimed_id=http://yo.rediris.es/
&openid.assoc_handle={HMAC-SHA1}{5a3294ef}{A8uNlg==}
```

After this, login, redirections... in the OP Provider , i need get the body response in http://localhost:5002/login?nonce=whatevercode

Thanks in advance

Comment: The HTTP request you shared is not an OpenID Connect request but an OpenID 2.0 request. Since OpenID 2.0 and OpenID Connect are radically different protocols (despite sharing the same "OpenID" moniker), you can't use the OpenID Connect handler to achieve what you want.

Comment: but, Is it possible to perform an authentication following the openid 2.0 protocol in aspcore 2.0? the op server only implement this spec. Thanks for the commentary, edit de question with your info

Comment: You can give https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenId.Providers a try ;)

Comment: Very good your library, I have managed to connect in dumb mode an openid-attribute-exchange-1 ; I'm going to analyze it to see if I can connect using the simple registration protocol